# How do I prove the uniqueness of additive identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

First, suppose $i_1$ and $i_2$ are additive identity in ring R. From the definition of "additive identity" $a+i_1=a$ such that there is $a$ $\in$ $R$, including for $a=i_2$, so $i_2+i_1=i_2$. But $i_2$ is also an additive identity, so there $a \in R$ making $a+i_2=a$. Then $a=i_1$. Then $i_1+i_2=i_1$. Since this is a ring, addition is commutative, so $i_1+i_2=i_2+i_1$. Thus, $i_2+i_1=i_1$. Since $i_2+i_1=i_2$ and $i_2+i_1=i_1$, $i_2+i_1$ is the same element of $i_2$ and is the same as $i_1$, making $i_2=i_1$. Is this how you show it's unique? If not, can someone show me how to prove it's unique.

Comment: Yes: this is how you show it is unique.

Comment: Your proof is correct; although it could be made a lot less verbose by just saying $ i_1 = i_1 + i_2 = i_2 + i_1 = i_2 $.

Comment: That's a little verbose, but essentially it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, although you can trim it down a bit; for clarity's sake.

> If $i_n$ is an additive identity, then for any $a$ in the ring: $~a+i_n=a~$ and $i_n+a=a$, by definition and the commutative property of addition in abelian groups.
>
> If *any* $i_1, i_2$ are both additive identities, then we have: $i_1+i_2=i_1$ and $i_1+i_2=i_2$.
>
> Thus for *any* additive identities $i_1,i_2$, then $i_1=i_2$.
>
> That is: The additive identity for a ring is unique.
>
> $\Box$