# How to prove the uniqueness of multiplicative identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $i_1, i_2 \in R$ which are multiplicative identity. Let $a$ also be in $R$. Then $a*i_1=a$ which means $a=i_2$. Thus, $i_2*i_1=i_2$. Now $a*i_2=a$, then $a=i_1$ hence $i_1*i_2=i_1$. Now how do I show that $i_1=i_2$?

Comment: $i_1 = i_1*i_2 = i_2$.

Comment: Or more clearly $i_1 = i_1*identity$.  As $i_2$ is an identity, $i_1 = i_1*i_2$.  But $i_1$ is also an identity so $i_1*i_2 = i_2$.  So $i_1 = i_1*1_2 = i_2$.

Comment: Are the identities right identities only?

Comment: This is only different from your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1798766/29335 by notation, otherwise it is exactly the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close. Let's suppose that both $i_1$ and $i_2$ $\in R$ are the multiplicative identity.

If $a\in R$, then $a\star i_1=a=i_2\star a$ by definition since $i_1$ and $i_2$ are both the identity.

$i_1=i_1\star i_2$ since $i_2$ is the identity.

But $i_1\star i_2=i_2$ since $i_1$ is also the identity.

So, $i_1=i_2$ and the identity is unique.

Answer (score 2):

$$ i_2  =  i_1 * i_2  =  i_1 $$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that? How do I deduce that from what I've done?